# How to remove specific ID based on specific condition (e.g., different value in variable)?

Tags: sas, proc-sql, longitudinal

I have 8 observations per subject ID. All subjects were asked to complete 8 tasks (i.e., 8 observations) in the same session, i.e., each ID should have an identical session time. However, in my dataset, for ID #5, 2 observations had the same session time, and 6 observations had the same session time. Therefore, I would like to exclude ID#5 from this example dataset. I have multiple IDs in my extended dataset. I would appreciate if someone could provide an example code to remove IDs with different session times.

Example dataset:

```
data work;
input id SessionTime v1 v2 v3;
datalines;
1   18.2    2   3   6
1   18.2    3   7   8
1   18.2    4   6   12
1   18.2    6   8   10
1   18.2    8   9   22
1   18.2    9   10  25
1   18.2    10  12  30
1   18.2    12  17  4
2   16.7    3   7   6
2   16.7    4   11  10
2   16.7    5   10  8
2   16.7    7   12  20
2   16.7    9   13  23
2   16.7    10  14  28
2   16.7    11  16  2
2   16.7    13  21  4
3   18.2    4   11  8
3   18.2    5   15  6
3   18.2    6   14  18
3   18.2    8   16  21
3   18.2    10  17  26
3   18.2    11  18  0
3   18.2    12  20  2
3   18.2    14  25  6
4   19.3    5   15  4
4   19.3    6   19  16
4   19.3    7   18  19
4   19.3    9   20  24
4   19.3    11  21  7
4   19.3    12  22  0
4   19.3    13  24  4
4   19.3    15  29  2
5   20.3    6   19  14
5   20.3    7   23  17
5   28.4    8   22  22
5   28.4    10  24  5
5   28.4    12  25  5
5   28.4    13  26  2
5   28.4    14  28  0
5   28.4    16  33  12
;
run;
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you format the example dataset properly?

Answer (score 1):

`Proc SQL` by default performs automatic remerging when you select columns that are not in a group.  This feature can be leveraged to filter your data using a `having` clause.

Example:

Select the ids that have exactly 8 rows and only 1 session.

```
proc sql;
  create table want as
  select * from have
  group by id
  having count (*) = 8 and count (distinct sessiontime) = 1
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just calculate how many observations there are per group.

```
proc sql;
create table want as select *,count(*) as nobs
  from have group by id,sessiontime
;
```

It will then be easy to exclude the groups that do not have 8 observations.

```
proc means data=want;
  where nobs=8 ;
run;
```